# Central Social Media Icons Under header ...HELP :(

Tags: php, html, css, header

I'm pretty clueless when it comes to code but I have tweaked and customized numerous sites before but for some reason my mind has gone blank and I have tried every which way possible to display social media icons that link to their corresponding websites, in the middle, under my header.

I have tried this:

```
    <div id="social-icons">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/danidolldesigns"><img  
    src="IMAGE_URL" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

and

```
<img src="http://danidolldesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05
/twitter_icon.png" alt="Twitter Icon" class="aligncenter/>
```

and various combinations  in every file I can find... css, html,header.php,page.php etc etc...

I just don't know where I'm going wrong, I have tried every possible answer I can find on the net and I'm probably missing something really obvious but I'm stumped :(

Comment: You're missing a quote in `class="aligncenter`. I don't know if that will solve your issue, but you should post a little bit more code and the CSS so we can identify the issue.

Comment: To be able to see how your file behaves, you need to add the relevant code for your _header_. In the best case, produce a working, and editable sample of your issue using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).